# Swift Xcode aspect-fit behaviour using AutoLayout on a UIImageView inside a containerView

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, autolayout, constraints

I have a embedded containerview inside my viewcontroller that leads to a UIPageController. Then the UIPageController loads images from a 3rd VC controller.

So it just a simple image swipe / image carousel.

What I cant get to work is autolayout on the UIImage. My containerview has a maring top 0 right 0 left 0 and a height of 200pt with aspect ratio set.

Bellow it some other information shows eg title / text etc.

But all images appears zoomed in/croped in the containerview.

So how can I make the images scale and fit inside the container view?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you assign explicit height to the imageView through autolayout ?

Answer (score 0):

set the image view's contentmode to scale aspect fit to see as much of the image as possible.

```
imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
```